# How can i retrieve correctly video tags with the js sdk?

Tags: javascript, api, dailymotion-api

I have an account where I have fake videos. I want to grab all videos with a specific tag (a year, or a place). I know all the tags for all the videos.

But, when I use the API (either the API explorer either with the js sdk) to grab all videos with the tag "2021", it answers me video where "2021" is not set in tags. Furthermore, it is the only tag working.

This my API call:

```
DM.api('/user/'+user_id+'/videos', {tags:"2021"}, arg => console.log(arg)
```

But one of my answer has not the corresponding tag.

Is someone has any clue on this behaviour ?

Comment: Your API call is good, the problem comes from an inconsistency in our Data, we will try to fix it as soon as poosible